# Notifications - filter out service accounts

Tags: azure-devops

We have the following subscription notification in our DevOps setup:

[image]

I would like to stop notifications if the change was done by the '*Project Collection Build Service [xxxx]*`' service account.

What filter should I use? Is a filter the right approach?

Example of notifications:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change "<>" to "=" in Operator so that you don't receive notification of changes to work items from the specified account.
[image]

I tested it with your filter criteria and it not work. I will still get notification. However, after I try to change "<>" to "=", the strange thing is that I will not receive notifications of changes to work items from the specified account. It worked.